# Math.ceil(x) using while loop

Tags: python-3.x, math, while-loop, do-while, ceil

Last time i was learning math module and I can not understand how math.ceil() works.
I was trying to use it with while loop, but I do not know how exacly it works.
Here is my little code:

```
import math

x = 20.4
y = 20.4

x = math.ceil(x)

while y != x:
    y += 0.1
    print(y)
```

It just can not stop calculating, why is that?
It even prints numbers like 20152.599999987233 or higher.

Comment: When you say you "can not understand how `math.ceil()` works", do you mean its *purpose* or underlying algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has [issues](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) with comparing two floating point numbers, due to problems with precision/rounding. Python actually evaluates `y` to the closest approximation of 21.0 when you expect it to be 21. Due to this, they're not equal and the condition of `y != x`  never evaluates to `False`, causing the infinite loop you're experiencing.

You can use the `math.isclose` function instead of using equality to fix the issue:

```py
import math

x = math.ceil(20.4)
y = 20.4

while not math.isclose(x,y):
    y += 0.1
    print(y)
```

Now, your loop should terminate when `y` is "close to" 21 - this was my output:

```
20.5
20.6
20.700000000000003
20.800000000000004
20.900000000000006
21.000000000000007
```

Comment: Actually, 21 is representable exactly as a floating point number. The problem is that 0.1 is not. It would be as a decimal type, which python has in the `decimal` module.